# Operation timed out - received only 0 responses in cassandra cql

Tags: python, cassandra

While i am try to insert bulk of data from .cql file.I am getting the below mentioned error.

```
<stdin>:70144:WriteTimeout: Error from server: code=1100 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

what i should do? i also increased write_request_timeout_in_ms in **cassandra.yaml**

My version of **cassandra** is **3.9** and **python** - **2.7**

Please anyone help me to fix this! Any answer is appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What amount of data are you trying to write? It seems that it is too much data, so that it can`t be handled. Could you separate the data and load it via batches? This would be a better approach instead of increasing the timeout.